# write a new line text file python every 4 tabs

Tags: python

If I have the following data that is printed seperated by tabs using

```
print str(z).translate(None,"([]){},\"'").replace(' ','\t')

0.016611783537845426    0.5728972505882961  0.1723653381777387   0.44730982873820446    10  11  10  0.016611783537845426     0.5728972505882961 0.2526385373738682  0.03281263933004819 10  12  10  0.016611783537845426    0.5728972505882961  0.509414248773428
```

How can i write to a new txt file  but start new line every say 4 tabs. so to get 4 columns.

have tried many variations of \n but im rubbsih.

for example:

```
 open("file.txt", "w").write('\n'.join(str(z).translate(None,"([]){},\"'").replace(' ','\t')))
```

returns a newline for every character.

Comment: Please post what code you've tried already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `grouper` recipe from the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
import itertools as it
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return it.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Then you can generate the output as:

```
values = str(z).translate(None,"([]){},\"'").split()
output = '\n'.join('\t'.join(x for x in g if x) for g in grouper(4, values))
```

Or if you want to write it to a file, use `f.writelines`:

```
f.writelines('\t'.join(x for x in g if x) + '\n' for g in grouper(4, values))
```

Comment: `writelines` doesn't add newlines so you're better off joining as in your answer and using `write`.

Comment: NIklas and agf thank you. `writelines` was working for me but i combined your code niklas with `write` as suggested by agf and it came out just right!

Comment: @user1322296: Yes, if that works for your, it's completely valid. If you want to use `writelines`, I edited the example to make it work. Have fun (and feel free to upvote and accept this answer if it was helpful to you :)

Comment: Ah i see i was using writelines the way i first learned i.e. wrong

`f = open('file.txt','w')
f.writelines('\t'.join(x for x in g if x) for g in grouper(4, values))
f.close()`

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
text = str(z).translate(None,"([]){},\"'").replace(' ','\t')

# convert to list
x = text.split()
# group by four items
x = [x[0::4],x[1::4],x[2::4],x[3::4]]
# convert back to text lines
print "\n".join(" ".join(i) for i in [x[0::4],x[1::4],x[2::4],x[3::4]])
```

Comment: thank you jiri buti think this might get quite big when i start dealing with much larger files